# Why I cannot use flask.request.headers as a hinting types?

Tags: python, flask

I'm going to use `flask.request.headers` as a hinting types in input parameter of a method, but the following error is raised:

```
...
raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

Code:

```py
def events_webhook(header: flask.request.headers) -> None:
    """Webhook for Google Calendar events."""

    print(header)
```

I called the above code using this:

```py
@api.route('/calendar/event/webhook', methods=["POST"])
def gcalendar_event_webhook():
    try:
        if flask.request.method == "POST":
            return RestHandler.handle_success(
                gutils.events_webhook(request.headers),  # here
                request=request, log_payload=False
            )
        else:
            return RestHandler.handle_exception(
                exception="Request method is not POST.", request=request
            )
    except Exception as exc:
        return RestHandler.handle_exception(exc, request)
```

Comment: are you sure this error is about type hinting? Can you post the full traceback error, because it looks like the kind of error you get when a DB instance is not initialized in flask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flask.request.headers` contains the headers of the current request. It's not a class, it's an instance. Which does not exist outside of a request context, hence the specific error.

The class of that object should usually be [`werkzeug.datastructures.Headers`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.Headers).

Comment: Thank you. So instead of using `flask.request.headers` as hinting type I imported the `Header` (i.e. `from werkzeug.datastructures import Headers`) and used it as hinting type.